# How to remove the extra parenthesis added by Prettier?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I'm using Prettier plugin to format my code on VSCode. And I've got .prettierrc to configure it. When I save the code, it adds extra parenthesis on the ternary operator. I have disabled the extra parenthesis for the arrow function using `"arrow-parens": avoid`, however, there doesn't seem to be any option for ternary operator.

```
  const kafkaEnabled = config => (config.kafka ? true : false)
```

Comment: Seems like there is no option for now https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3805

Comment: Though in your example you could just coerce to boolean (since your condition relies on implicit coercion already) `const kafkaEnabled = config => Boolean(config.kafka)`

Comment: @pilchard - Thanks for the suggestion, above one is just one occurrence, but I need to deal with the extra parenthesis everywhere in the code.